# Kendo Grid, dynamically adding column in $timeout, ends up in 'kendo.all.js:121639Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined'

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Kendo Grid, dynamically adding column in $timeout, ends up in 'kendo.all.js:121639Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined'

Please refer DOJO http://dojo.telerik.com/@datha_k/axITa
I am adding columns on click of button button with little $timeout. I don't understand why this piece of code gives error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined" in file kendo.all.js:121639.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I think k-rebind creates the problem with other updates in the gridOptions in your example. If you remove or change the value to gridOptions, it works as expected.

Here is the another working example.

[DOJO Example](http://dojo.telerik.com/exesE)